# How can I sign a text by certificate in SQL Server and provide PKCS#7 signature?

Tags: sql, sql-server, certificate, digital-signature, pkcs#7

In my app i need to implement digital signature of some text, extracted from DB data (customer bill, for example), to send a text by e-mail together with it's signature in PKCS#7 format. Both because of high load and data volumes, and a fact that an e-mail app is provided by external developers, it's highly desired to include a text signature in SQL Server resultset, which returns all the data (e-mail attachments) to e-mail app.

The problem is that SQL Server uses x509 v.3 certificate format. It is not a problem while importing certificate and a key - I can convert it to x509 v.3 using OpenSSL before import, it's a one-time deal. But is there a way to convert a SQL Server signature to PKCS#7 format inside SQL Server, or do I have to implement a signing process outside of it?

Comment: So you think the best use of the SQL server CPU cycles is doing RSA operations... You must have a lot of spare cycles. How about signing the documents in your client, on the peripheral CPUs?

Comment: Hi, Remus, thank you for reply! In my case, this architectural approach - to use SQL Server for document signing - was due to our existed software design. An e-mail is almost a "black box" app and is expensive in development and maintenance. It gets all necessary data from SQL Server stored procedure, so, it might be much cheaper and easier to add necessary signature to a result set. About CPU load - it's not an issue, because this process runs in off-peak hours.